# setTimeout() won't trigger the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to trigger the function in 5ooo second again and again with first_pic variable that contains different integer. Every time this function runs it adds plus 1 to first_pic variable, apparently it won't work, please help.

```
function slide(){
    var total_pic = $("#slide_show").children().length;
    var first_pic = $("#slide_show li:first-child").css('z-index',total_pic).index()+1;
    $("#slide_show li:nth-child("+first_pic+")").fadeOut(4000, function(){
        first_pic = first_pic + 1;
    });
    setTimeout(slide, 5000);
};
slide();
```

variable adds 1 nicely, but setTimeout doesn't trigger function again

Comment: FYI, 5000 seconds is 5000000 milliseconds (which is the unit used in `setTimeout()`). Of course, you probably meant milliseconds as 5000 seconds (~1.3 hours) is a long time to wait for a browser event

Comment: And what about using `setInterval()` for delayed recurrence ?

Comment: The only real difference would be that with setTimeout you can have the function fire immediately and then again per interval, where as setInterval first gives you the interval delay then fires the function

Comment: i tryed setInterval with 5000 milliseconds, won't work as well

Answer (score 3):

Your `first_pic` is a local variable within the `slide` function. That means that each time you call `slide`, you get a new `first_pic` variable. Your `fadeOut` callback will update the `first_pic` that it is a closure for but the `slide` called by `setTimeout` will get its own `first_pic`. If you want to use the same `first_pic` for every execution of `slide` you will have to make it global or make its value persistent with [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) or a cookie.

Have a look at this, it might clarify that's going on:

```
function slide() {
    var first_pic = 5;
    $('#fade').fadeOut(1000, function() {
        first_pic = first_pic + 1;
        $('#fade').show();
        $('#out').text(first_pic);
    });
    setTimeout(slide, 2000);
};
slide();
```

Live version (with HTML): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/PRaLH/

And compare it to how this behaves:

```
var first_pic = 5;
function slide() {
    $('#fade').fadeOut(1000, function() {
        first_pic = first_pic + 1;
        $('#fade').show();
        $('#out').text(first_pic);
    });
    setTimeout(slide, 2000);
};
slide();
```

Live version: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Ntqjh/

Comment: so silly me...
I made variable global, pushed them out of function and now it's works.